# Are mesh plots with Octave/XQuartz/GNUPlot supposed to be slow?

Tags: gnuplot, octave, xquartz

Rotating a 3D mesh plot is very slow in Octave when used with XQuartz and GNUPlot in OSX Mavericks. I understand slow is hard to quantify, but what I mean here is, that upon dragging the mouse, the plot lags behind and skips a lot of frames, to the point where it's even a little hard to see where you'll end up once you are done dragging.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Hold the `Ctrl`-key while rotating. This displays only the axis during rotation and redraws the mesh only when you have finished rotating.

Comment: That helps a lot. Also, it sounds like XQuartz is not at fault, but rather gnuplot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am on Debian, `ver` tell me that:

```
GNU Octave Version: 4.0.0
GNU Octave License: GNU General Public License
Operating System: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1 (2015-05-24) x86_64
```

I have a 1000x1000 mesh and it is extremely slow, in my setup the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19954741/15485 does not work.

I had a look at https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Introduction-to-Plotting.html and call `graphics_toolkit ("fltk")` before my call to `mesh`: it improved a lot, it is not super fast but at least I can rotate the mesh.

Comment: Have you seen the answer from Christoph on holding `Ctrl-` to rotate?

Comment: @Miquel Yes I did, I wrote it in my answer :-)